# Evaluating the preservation of characteristics between two datasets

Tags: python, dataset, evaluation

I am generating a new dataset based on the input of an initial one. The dataset is about food preferences. The columns structure is as follows:

- 4 columns contain information about restaraunt options: title, type
  of food, lunch serving time, dinner serving time.
- The other 6 columns contain demographic inforation in a categorical manner for
  expample gender, age group, matital_status etc.

Every row of the original dataset represents a customer at any of the contained restaurants.
What type of metrics/tests should I run in order to evaluate whether the generated dataset preserves the characteristics contained in the original dataset ?

Comment: what are you preserving in the original dataset?  you have to label encode or one hot encode your categorical data.  you have to impute missing values.  you have to normalize numeric data. there are several preprocessing tasks to consider.  Next, you need to verify data types and then use value_count to explore your numeric data. show me what you have done so far

Comment: The main thing to validate is that the generated dataset reproduces the behaviour of the original. 
Data types and the order are identical for each column between the two sets. There are no missing values in both sets. 
Besides the lunch serving time and dinner serving time which are datetime64 the rest of the columns are all str. 
Categorical demographic data are encoded suing .astype('category').cat.codes

Comment: you can use df1['Column1'].isin(df2['Column1']).  Post 5 rows of the data from dataframe1 and 5 rows from the resulting dataframe.

Comment: you can use a left join merge to see what is different in terms of new records.

Comment: if your using keras, you will want to one hot encode to prevent losing categorical level ranking.

Comment: My question is more oriented towards what types of tests I should run and compare results among the two datasets. For instance, since I don't have continuous data is there a point of using Euclidean Distance ? Since I have categorical data how can I set up a chi-squared test in the original dataset and compare the results with a chi-squared test run on the generated dataset ?

Comment: what is the target label your trying to classify?  you can get the probabilities of the logistic regression classifier.  you can use kmeans and tse to see how the data clusters.  pca may help

Comment: @GoldenLion the link you posted leads back to this thread. I don't have a target label

Comment: https://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html  df["type_of_food"].value_counts(), df["age_group"].value_counts labelEncode the gender and martial status.  Look at the probabilities between the categorical rankings for observed behavior.  visualize using a heatmap

Comment: here is how to implement chi-test in python  https://machinelearningmastery.com/chi-squared-test-for-machine-learning/

Comment: Covariance

1) A measure of how two quantities vary together
2) if the distance from the x mean and the distance from the y mean are positive than the point is positively correlated

1/m (x-x_mean)*(y-y_mean)  if positive then positively correlated

if y is below the mean then the variable is negatively correlated

pearson correlation = covariance/(std of x)*(std of y)

equals

pearson correlation = variability due to codependence/ independant variability -1 no correlation and 1 totally correlated

Comment: def pearson_r(x,y):
    """Compute Pearson correlation coefficient between two arrays."""
    # Compute correlation matrix: corr_mat
    corr_mat=np.corrcoef(x,y)
#covariance/(std of x)*(std of y)
    # Return entry [0,1]
    return corr_mat[0,1]

Comment: pearson_r will tell you what columns are relating.  you can use pearson_r to compare the original with the new dataframe.  if there is a change pearson_r coefficients will change.

Comment: @GoldenLion I found the URL that you suggest as well, my issue is that although related I can't directly link it with my case. Besides the gender all my other (demographic) categorical attributes have at least 3 categories. In addition, shall I make with a contigeny table including all 6 categorical variables ? Is this how the test works ?

Comment: the number of categorical fields does not matter.  you can hot encode each one then concatenate the one hot coded columns to a resulting dataframe.  One hot encode if categorical ranking matters otherwise you can use astype('category') as you previously did.

Answer (score 0):

```
 print("pearson_r weight to height",pearson_r(height[weight_filter],weight))
 print("pearson_r age to weight",pearson_r(age[weight_filter],weight))
 print("pearson_r education to age",pearson_r(real_income,age))
 print("pearson_r education to income",pearson_r(real_income,education))
```

pearson_r will give you the correlation between the columns.  you can store pearson_r results and use them to compare if dataframe has changed.

Comment: can I use though pearson_r  with categorical variables ? Because there are no continuous/numerical data in the columns

Comment: pearson_r shows the correlation between two features.  one hot encoding converts the category to feature columns.  the product between a feature column and the other features reveals the total number of combinations.  each combination can have a pearson_r value.

Comment: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat501/lesson/15/15.1   Look at this statistical explanation of logistic regression coefficient and categorical rank levels

Comment: I am generating the the correlation matrices, let's say including only the demographics attributes. I need to compare the two matrices. One way that I found out is Euclidean distance. However, given the input of the 2 matrices, the output is also a matrix and not a value. How I can interpret that ?

Comment: Also I can't understand the syntax what do in the first example pearson_r(height[weight_filter],weight)). What do you mean by [weight_filter]. To filter the dataset given a weight_value  e.g. if the df is the dataframe df[df['weight'] < 90] ? If yes why would I do that ?

Comment: I applied a filter to my code.  It doesn't apply to your case. ignore it.